# Using a component defined in a .jsx file in a typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

We have purchased a react theme with the intent to use its component in our web application, and we ended up with some issues getting them to transpile, we got that solved. However, we're now running into issues with types.

I believe the issue here is that typescript doesn't like that props doesn't have a type defined on it and is defaulting to IntrinsicAttributes. I'd like to be able to use the components without modification.

**The error:**

```
(TS) Property 'content' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Card> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Read...'
```

**home.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from './test';

type HomeProps = RouteComponentProps<{}>;

export default class Home extends React.Component<HomeProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <Card content="but why doesn't this work?" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

**test.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
        {this.props.content}
        </div>;
    }

}
export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a new attribute, try creating a new interface for test file and define a interface in any of the typedefinition file as shown below,

```
interface Card {
     content: any;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: We're trying to use it without having to define types for each of the properties/components. We have probably 100 components, each of them with at least 10 properties, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

React defaults props and state to have the type `{}`, and this is why it claims `content` does not exist in this example.

Perhaps better than implementing the interface for each component is to do the following trick (which is not the prettiest):

In the .tsx file:

```
import OriginalCard from './test';

/* tslint:disable */
const Card: any = OriginalCard; 
/* tslint:enable */
```

And the you should be able to use `Card` without getting the error.